# TypeError Unsupported operand types: string * App\Models\Price (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\controldehoras\resources\views\timestamps\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

Tengo un `foreach` y dentro de él guardo el resultado de multiplicar dos montos en un `array` (Lo he hecho dándole a ambos campos, el tipo `string`, `bigInteger` y `decimal` y aún así da el mismo error pero cambia el tipo de dato en el mensaje).

El error es el siguiente `TypeError Unsupported operand types: string *`  si cambo el tipo de dato en la migración, cambia en el mensaje.

Esto pasa a partir del tercer registro, con los primeros dos no da el error.

```
@foreach($timestamps as $timestamp)
<tr>
    @role('Administrator|Coordinator')
        <td scope="row">{{ $timestamp->first_name }} {{ $timestamp->last_name }}</td>
    @endrole
    <td scope="row">{{ $timestamp->subject->subject }}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{ $timestamp->hours }}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($timestamp->date)) }}</td>
    <td scope="row">
        @if($timestamp->status  == 'CREATED') 
            <i class="fas fa-clock text-danger"></i> {{ __('Waiting') }}
        @elseif ($timestamp->status  == 'CONFIRMED') 
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle text-success"></i> {{ __('Confirmed') }}
        @endif
    </td>
    <td scope="row">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="{{ route('timestamps.show', $timestamp->id) }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-1 mr-1">{{ __('View') }}</a>

            @if ($timestamp->status == 'CONFIRMED')
                <a href="{{ route('timestamps.edit', $timestamp->id) }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success disabled mb-1 mr-1" disabled="disabled">{{ __('Edit') }}</a>
            @else
                <a href="{{ route('timestamps.edit', $timestamp->id) }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success mb-1 mr-1">{{ __('Edit') }}</a>
            @endif
        
            @role('Administrator|Coordinator')
                @if ($timestamp->status == 'CREATED')
                    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'timestamps.status']) !!}
                    {{ Form::hidden('status', 'CONFIRMED') }}
                    {{ Form::hidden('id', $timestamp->id) }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info mr-2" onclick="return confirm('¿Todos los datos son correctos?');">{{ __('Confirm') }}</button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                @endif
            @endrole
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

   @php $operation[] = $timestamp->hours * $timestamp->price; @endphp

@endforeach
```

Esta es la línea que marca el error:

```
@php $operation[] = $timestamp->hours * $timestamp->price; @endphp
```

Luego imprimo la suma de todos los valores de dicho array:

```
<p><strong>Total a pagar: </strong> @php $total_to_pay = array_sum($operation) @endphp {{ $total_to_pay ?? '' }} </p>
```

Mi controlador:

```
$timestamps = Timestamp::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(25);
        
        $total_timestamps = Timestamp::selectRaw('users.*, timestamps.date, timestamps.hours, timestamps.comment, sum(hours) as total')
                                    ->join('users', 'timestamps.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                    ->groupBy('timestamps.id')
                                    ->orderBy('timestamps.id', 'desc')
                                    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                    ->paginate(25);

        $total = $total_timestamps->sum('total', 'total');


        $total_confirmed_timestamps = Timestamp::where('timestamps.status', 'CONFIRMED')
                                    ->selectRaw('users.*, timestamps.date, timestamps.hours, timestamps.comment, sum(hours) as total_confirmed')
                                    ->join('users', 'timestamps.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                    ->groupBy('timestamps.id')
                                    ->orderBy('timestamps.id', 'desc')
                                    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                    ->paginate(25);

        $total_confirmed = $total_confirmed_timestamps->sum('total_confirmed');

        return view('timestamps.index', compact('timestamps', 'total', 'total_confirmed'));
```

Nota: Si es necesario otra información, actualizo la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en el error es que estas intentando hacer una operación (*) donde no acepta un string en este caso $timestamp->hours

Si dices que solo pasa a partir desde el 3er registro, verifica que existe ese valor haciéndole un debug (DD) en el controlador.

```php
dd($timestamp); #antes del return
```

Tambien prueba convirtiendo el string a integer

```php
int($timestamp->hours)
```

Ya que estas utilizando selectRaw, podrias convertirlo desde la misma query con CAST

```sql
CAST(timestamps.hours AS int)
```

Comment: Okey dejéme intentar, algo de eso ya hice. Te escribo cuando lo intente. Gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, tenía otro código en el controlador... Entre pruebas y pruebas... No estba llegando el valor de `price`, no entiendo como registraba los dos primeros (Por temas de tiempo no pude revisar).